# C# generated client from swagger not working because of date implementation

Tags: c#, datetime, swagger, openapi, auto-generate

I have a swagger definition which is already finalized so I am not able to alter attributes or propose changes.
This swagger file has various date definitions like this:

```
fromDate:
 description: |
   - en - fromDate.....
 type: string
  format: date
```

In java clients this is generated as a *Date* attribute. In C# there is no basic implementation of *Date* but just *DateTime* which is taken as the generated datatype. 
This is the same for all of the 4 ways I tried when generating the client:

```
Swagger Editor with C# Client generation
Swagger Editor with C# #2 Client generation  (RestSharp 2)
Open API generator with C# Client generation
Open API generator with C# #2 Client generation (RestSharp 2)
```

I would expect a serialization pattern like yyyy-mm-dd to be created in the c# client to match the date type but this is not the case. Dates are always serialized as full date/time/timezone strings. This is not working for the server application.

The official [documentation](https://swagger.io/specification/#dataTypes) says

**string    date    As defined by full-date - RFC3339**

[RFC339](https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14) full date says

```
 full-date = date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday
```

As expected my client produces wrong output data (for example *2020-12-31T23:59:60Z*)  and crashes when it parses incoming data in the api client class (crash occurs before I can handle the input).

When I alter the swagger to have a string type with a pattern as suggested in other posts it works but this is not how it should be, I must use the predefined swagger file.

How can I create the clients or add a special pattern that gets automatically called by the client?

Cheers

Comment: Is `fromDate` in path/query or in body?

Comment: What Swagger client generator are you using? NSwag or Swashbuckle?

Comment: @BrunoZell  I use https://editor.swagger.io and https://mermade.github.io/openapi-gui/, and select C# or C#V2 as a client so it`s the most "pure" implementations

Comment: @weichch in the body. Problem is the parser that deserialises the dates in the body json (serverside after I send a request with a date or clientside when I receive a respponse with a date)

Comment: I thought if you generate code from swagger editor, there's a `SwaggerDateTimeConverter` created for serializing / deserializing date in body. Is that not functioning well?

Comment: @weichch I don`t see anything like that in the generated code. I try now to use the configuration setting but this will overwrite all existing patterns I suppose. I would have expected to have it automatically in the generated model class OR so I can adjust the pattern with every call